# No update notifications for gnome-software: Which log to check?

Tags: gnome, notification, gnome-software, update-notifier

I'm not getting update notifications (since a couple of months) for gnome-software though available updates (e.g. for `snaps` and `flatpaks`) show in the application and automatic updates are enabled.

e.g. OS Updates like this one or nvidia driver updates or one of my snaps/flatpaks (audacity, godot, etc.)
[image]

I'm a bit lost at finding the right log to see what error keeps those notifications from appearing.

```
gnome-software 3.38.1 on Ubuntu 21.04
```

That's what I did find after a reboot:

```
Aug 30 07:51:15 system gnome-software[2066]: not handling error failed for action get-updates-historical: failed to build result for b8f11848dfcbf441df375b9f11b0e42d085f688b
Aug 30 07:51:16 system gnome-software[2066]: not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/InRelease
Aug 30 07:51:17 system gnome-software[2066]: CSS parse error 1:107: Using one color stop with linear-gradient() is deprecated.
Aug 30 07:51:17 system snap-store[2120]: not handling error failed for action get-updates-historical: failed to build result for b8f11848dfcbf441df375b9f11b0e42d085f688b
```

Comment: perhaps there are no updates available... which apps specifically? Please [edit] your question with further detail to make your question useful.

Comment: @24601 What does work though, is the notification after I've installed OS updates when the system needed a restart. For the time being I consider setting myself a reminder to check for updates every week or so.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The Software says that it need to upgrade chromium and opera but when i click update, says snap does not have update available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gnome devs know best, so you should ask them. Check an answer on [gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/issues/1531#note_1301248).

> We don’t support gnome-software 40.x any more upstream, sorry. The latest stable release is gnome-software 41.1.

I suppose that the issue is fixed once Ubuntu decides to update their `gnome-software` version. You could always use Arch Linux if you feel updates trickle in too slowly.